# Juego que corta áreas, problema con el corte de área

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un juego en Javascript, mi avance consiste en avanzar con las fechas para marcar todo el camino recorrido, lo que me falta y tengo dudas de hacerlo es cuando se forme una **area cerrada** con alguno de los bordes debiese pintarse con otro color haciendo parecer una área inservible

**Edit 1:** necesito un algoritmo que me ayude a realizar lo que busco. aunque no en codigo fuente. un algoritmo lo mas sencillo posible y entendible seria de gran ayuda.

**Edid 1.1:** necesito un algoritmo, formulas matematicas, se muy bien que se puede hacerlo de forma bruta

**Edit2:** el juego que estoy pretendiendo a hacer es: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRVXKUoU5OY

1.- el borde no debería ser penetrado.

2.- el area a cortar debe ser todo el recorrido

3.- deberia pasar entre el camino, para formar otro camino, serian 2 areas

4.- cuando se corte, el borde de esa area deberia ser el nuevo borde del area total

dejo un screenshot del juego que estoy realizando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas preguntando por una duda que tienes, no por un problema de codificación, recomiendo que re-formules tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: preguntas: 1.-- las lineas del "camino" ¿tienen o no tienen permitido cruzar las otras lineas del "camino"? ahora esta permitido, y en caso quedar asi: ¿como se define el area a pinar? ¿es el total de lo marcado o solo el rectángulo mas próximo al borde del "area"?. 2.-- Ahora el "camino" tiene permitido salirse del "area", esto: ¿se quiere asi? o se quiere que este confinado (al "area"). ¿Seria mucha molestia aclarar todas las reglas del movimiento-juego?

Comment: @EmanuelVe ya edite mi pregunta, puse imagen y video para que se comprenda mucho mejor

Comment: @x-rw acá hay una mejor implementación del juego para que se entienda la idea y lo puedas tomar de ejemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hevzLLvRuI0

Comment: No estaria entendiendo bien cual es el problema. Si detectas una colision contra otra area cerrada, tienes coordenadas de inicio de tu linea, coordenadas de destino de la misma, y una direcion en la cual quieres pintar. Que cuesta agregar un poligono pintado en esa zona??

Answer (score 2):

encontré [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867647/find-close-path-or-region-using-recursive-method) algoritmo:

```
for each cell and until closed area not found
     if white and visitedValue = -1
        push cell to stack
        while stack has values and closed area not found
            pop cell from stack
            if invalid cell // Cell coordinates are invalid
                this area is not closed, so break from the while
            else
                if white
                    if visitedValue = -1
                    {
                        mark visited
                        push neighboring four cells to the stack
                    }
                    else
                        if visitedValue > currVisitNumber // The current cells are part of previous searched cell group, which was not a closed group.
                            this area is not closed, so break from the while
if closed area found
    show message
```

Como comentarios, tendrás que recorrer cada pixel de tu canvas y revisar el color de este, para saber si está `ocupado` o no. Toma en cuenta que tu canvas tiene `700x600 = 4200` celdas, las cuales estarás chequeando mediante el algoritmo una y otra vez, en base a alguna logica de revision. Esta logica puede ser:

- revisar cada vez que el usuario mueve el cursor: Esto implica que correrá MUCHAS veces y podría ser lento
- Correr cada ciertos intervalos de tiempo (500ms por ejemplo), utilizando `setInterval`, asegurándote que no corran más de una vez al mismo tiempo.

Además, podrías considerar no utilizar el canvas como tu matriz de datos, sino que tener un mapa (matriz bidimensional) que tenga al menos un orden de magnitud menos (420 celdas por ejemplo), asi el algoritmo demora menos tiempo y solo debes dibujar el mapa en el canvas como tu quieras.

espero haber ayudado

saludos

Comment: si me parece una buena forma de solucionar el problema

Answer (score -2):

1. Los bordes del CANVAS no pueden penetrarse eso ya lo tienes definido
   al crear el canvas si es fijo esta fácil saberlo y si es dinámico
   con respecto al ancho del navegador debes capturar el height y el
   width luego de crear el canvas para saber tus limites y no
   penetrarlos.
2. El área recortada debe ser un recorrido pero su inicio comienza
   desde un borde que sabes y termina con un borde que ya sabes donde
   esta ubicado en coordenadas X y Y en la sección 1 ya sabes como
   obtenerlo.
3. Viene lo complicado cuando ya tienes elementos creados y tus bordes
   ya no son rectos debes detectar colisión de objetos, para asi crear
   tus nuevos recorridos cerrados.
4. El Cursor de dibujo no debería estar fijo sino en movimiento y
   deberías permitir movimiento en sentido opuesto a la cara del canvas
   o recorrido ya trazado donde se este moviendo.

Comment: el inciso 1 esta claro, mi pregunta es si hay algun algoritmo eficiente para realizar mi objetivo, para cortar areas?